# CollapsingToolbar Title Padding for RTL languages

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How can I add some paddings into `collapsingToolbar` title for `RTL` languages,It is good for `LTR` laguages but for `RTL` it is like bellow..

Thanks very much

[image]

this is my layout..As you can see on right side of above image there title and it does not have any paddings..One method could be adding more spaces before title but it is not a wise way.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:transitionName="profile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:contentDescription="" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely something wrong there on the SDK.

try using

```
android:titleMarginEnd="0dp"
```

or

```
app:titleMarginEnd="0dp"
```

on the Toolbar.

It will not be perfect but at least it will not go further right than the end of the screen. Every other value I tried does not seem to work